# Group by data by 5 mintues sample

Tags: sql, sybase, sap-ase

I am having a table like this and I am storing epoch time as one column. I want to use epoch time column to group by data by 5 min

```
-------------------
Name | epoch_time |
A    | 1585977780 |
B    | 1585977780 |
C    | 1585978080 |
-------------------
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have Unix time, so you can use arithmetic:

```
select floor(epoch_time / (60 * 5)) * 60 * 5 as minutes_5, count(*)
from t
group by floor(epoch_time / (60 * 5)) * 60 * 5
```